# Function addNewDriver() is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

I want to call an onclick function but it gives me an error: `addnewDriver() is not defined`. How can I fix that?

This is where I call the function:

```html
<p><a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addNewDriver();">Add a new Driver</a></p>
```

This is my function:

```
function addNewDriver() 
{
    var pEntityType = <%=c.WIDOC_ENTITY_DRIVER%>;
    var pListEntities = <%=lListDrivers%>;
    location.href= "<%= c.url %>do/user/groupItemForm.step1.jsp?idClient=" + <%=pIdClient%> + "&listEntities:" + pListEntities + "&idGroup=" + <%=pIdGroup%> + "&entityType=" + pEntityType + "&<%= lBackButtonUrl %>"; 
}
```

Comment: and how do you serve the script that function is in? Because as shown, that's not valid JS and because the function body is invalid, the function never gets built. Also, rather than using `onclick`, you typically want to keep your JS on the JS side of the fence: find your button(s) and then add click handling using `addEventListener(`click`, () => addNewDriver())` or similar construction.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans It could be valid JS. The `<%= ... %>` are server side tags - they could be evaluating to acceptable string values. I'd imagine the fact that it's not complaining in console means that it's alright. It may not be, simply noting that I don't know if we can say *"that's not valid JS"* with any certainty. The fact that there are quotes around some and not others does leave me curious though.

Comment: Yes, hence "how do you serve the script" question. If this is the function that _browser_ gets, this won't work and it's very clear why the function is claimed to be undefined. If this is merely what the code is _on disk_ then we need to know what's serving that JS, and whether it's getting preprocessed at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you use quotation marks arround every <...> than it looks more like valid JS. So it look

```js
function addNewDriver() 
{
    var pEntityType = "<%=c.WIDOC_ENTITY_DRIVER%>";
    var pListEntities = "<%=lListDrivers%>";
    location.href= "<%= c.url %>do/user/groupItemForm.step1.jsp?idClient=" + "<%=pIdClient%>" + "&listEntities:" + pListEntities + "&idGroup=" + "<%=pIdGroup%>" + "&entityType=" + pEntityType + "&<%= lBackButtonUrl %>"; 
}
```

Try it like this.

Comment: @TylerRoper you are right about the quotes (the function does execute after adding them) but i wonder what this code aiming to do.